# Sendkey in selenium sends not a full value, instead of 0.7795 it sends 7795

Tags: python, string, selenium, integer, sendkeys

First I get the value, then I convert it to float to multiply it, but when I send it back as a string to a webpage instead of 0.7795 it sends 7795. Code below:

```
values = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='app']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/ul/li/form/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/input").get_attribute("value")
print_to_stdout(values)

valuesfl = float(values)

valuex2 = 2.0 * valuesfl

print_to_stdout(valuex2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='app']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/ul/li/form/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/input").send_keys(str(valuex2))
```

Tried to convert float to int, then to string, doesn't help...
If I do the same conversion simply in Python it works fine:

```
value1 = "0.390849"

integ = float(value1)
integmult = 2.0 * integ

integstr = str(integmult)

print(integstr)
```

Result:
0.781698

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

P.S: I simplified code for test:

```
valuetest = 0.1

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='app']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/ul/li/form/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/input").send_keys(valuetest)
```

It also doesn't work as desired, instead of 0.1 I get 1 on a webpage.

P.P.S:
Tried to do the same on this page, it sends correct value = 0.1 not 1. The page I have issue with is hotbit.io exchange page, I'm trying to enter price there. What can be the issue here? Does anyone know any workaround for this kind of issues?

Comment: I tested your process on another site to see what was sent to a textbox. It sent without any issue, and produced the desired output. Perhaps allow the website to load fully by including a waiting mechanism, before sending the keys.

Comment: what is print_to_stdout?

Comment: @ScottC I tried to add waiting, it didn't helped. I suspect it might have smth to do with page encoding.

Comment: @СергейКох print_to_stdout is printing values into terminal while program runs.

Comment: I simplified code for test:

valuetest = 0.1

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='app']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/ul/li/form/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/input").send_keys(valuetest)
It also doesn't work as desired, instead of 0.1 I get 1 on a webpage.

Comment: Tried to do the same on this page, it sends correct value = 0.1 not 1. The page I have issue with is hotbit.io exchange page, I'm trying to enter price there.

Comment: Did you trying sending `0,1` instead of `0.1`? Some websites use comma for decimal separation

Comment: What worked for me is to send 0.0.1 to get 0.1 =P Still curious what the reason.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to send 0.0.1 to get 0.1 =)